# converting flv to mp4

Tags: html, mencoder

I have converted the flv files into mp4 using the mencoder by using the following command

> **mencoder input.flv -o outout.mp4 -of lavf -oac mp3lame -lameopts abr:br=56 -ovc lavc -lavcopts
>   vbitrate=800:mbd=2:mv0:trell:v4mv:cbp:last_pred=3 -srate 22050 -ofps
>   24 -vf harddup**

It is converting the videos. But if i am using these videos in the html5 video tags. It is not playing. Please give me the suggestions.

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but do you have the original the flv was made from? the quality of the conversion would be way better if you were to create the mp4 from the original. Going Source -> FLV -> mp4 sounds like a bad idea

Comment: Which browser are you using to display the video? Some browsers cannot play mp4 as apart from html5 <video>

Answer (score 1):

lavf is pretty broken, is better for you to compress audio and video separately and then mux them with mp4box.
You can look how my scripts work:

http://teknoraver.net/software/mp4tools/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upload an open source video file format. ogg is, I believe, the current standard.

Here are some helpful links:

[Stack Overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541455/what-video-format-does-html5-use-and-why-is-it-compatible-with-safari-on-the-ipa)

[w3schools.com help with html5 video](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -c copy -copyts output.mp4
```