# Video/Audio streaming from Amazon S3 to phonegap apps?

Tags: html, wordpress, cordova, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I want to setup a CMS using wordpress on Amazon Ec2 & then create apps in different platforms using phonegap which will act as a presentation to the content in CMS.
The CMS will include high resolution video and audio.
These media content cannot be uploaded and streamed from youtube as the users will need to pay for access to them.

1. Can the video and audio be stored in a Amazon S3 bucket and streamed to the phonegap app?
2. What is the format the video & audio needs to be stored in so that they can be played on   devices of different platforms?
3. Will Amazon S3 suffice or should i look at a specialized streaming server? What will be the difference?

Regards
Ionade

Answer (score 1):

1. It can. I'm not sure on speeds.
2. If your using a HTML5 player generally speaking for IOS you will need to store your video in m4v and audio in mp3. Here is another question that might help - [What video format does HTML5 use and why is it compatible with Safari on the iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541455/what-video-format-does-html5-use-and-why-is-it-compatible-with-safari-on-the-ipa)